# iterating over sql result to produce new array of hashes

Tags: ruby

I have a result of `items` from SQL query.  I want to use these results to create a new array of hashes called `products`.  The path I'm on just doesn't seem right.  While iterating over each row, I need to conditional process some of the keys in the rows such as pseudo code below.

```
items = retrieve_items_from_db

products = items.map do |row|
  {
    row.each do | k, v|
      if k == "Color" 
        #go do something and add updated key, value pair to products
      else puts "SKEY:#{k} VALUE: #{v}"
        # add k,v to products
         k => v
    end
  }
end
```

Any pointers or suggestions?  I've tried using `inject({})` instead of `map`.

Comment: what is the purpose of this? also you are missing an `end` and `each` does not do what you think. You could clean it a up a bit like `products = items.map {|row| row.each_with_object({}) {|(k,v),obj| obj[k] = k == "Color" ? some_color_method(v) : v }}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're trying to do here would be cool, but we can't put conditional statements in hashes.

I.e. you can't do:

```
{
  if 2 == 2
    math: "correct"
  else
    math: "incorrect"
  end
}
```

You would need to instead do:

```
if 2 == 2
  { math: "correct" }
else
  { math: "incorrect" }
end
```

If you need to combine multiple hashes into one, the `Hash#merge` method is useful.

for example:

```
{ a: "a", b: "DEFAULT" }.merge({ b: "b", c: "c" })
# => { a: "a", b: "b", c: "c" }
```

You can see that the second hash has overridden values in the first one.

You could use `inject` here (or `reduce`, which does the same thing but is less scary-sounding), but since you're converting an array to an array, it'd be easier to use `map`.

```
products = items.map do |row|
 if row.keys.include?(:price)
   row = row.merge(price: "#{row[:price]} dollars")
 else
   row = row.merge(price: "not available for sale")
 end
 next row
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Made it a nested mapping and then flattened:

```
products = items.map do |row|
  row.map do |k, v|
    if k == "Color" 
      # go do something
      # add transformed k, v to products
    else
      puts "SKEY:#{k} VALUE: #{v}"
      k => v # add k, v to products
    end    
  end
end.flatten
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this way reads the easiest:

```
items = retrieve_items_from_db

products = items.map do |row|
  product = {}
  row.each do | k, v|
    if k == "Color" 
      #go do something and add updated key, value pair to products
      product[transform_key(k)] = transform_value(v)
    else
      puts "SKEY:#{k} VALUE: #{v}"
      # add k,v to products
      product[k] = v
    end
  end
  product
end
```

You can also use Hash::[] to convert an array of array-pairs into a Hash, but to me this is clunkier:

```
items = retrieve_items_from_db
products = items.map do |row|
  Hash[row.map do | k, v|
    if k == "Color" 
      #go do something and add updated key, value pair to products
      [transform_key(k), transform_value(v)]
    else
      puts "SKEY:#{k} VALUE: #{v}"
      # add k,v to products
      [k, v]
    end
  end]
end
```